# How to get the first element of a strsplit in R

Tags: r

I want to keep the first element of a string and store it in a variable.

In Python it would be `word = 'AAAAAA.BBBB'.split('.')[0]` but I can't find how to do it in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
variable = unlist(strsplit('AAAAAA.BBBB', '\\.'))[1]
```

Comment: Is the `unlist` not made unnecessary by the double bracket `[[1]]`?

Comment: I'm just wading in here, never used R - does it start indexing at `1` and not `0`? Weird.

Comment: @meedstrom : as i tried, `variable = strsplit('AAAAAA.BBBB', '\\.')[[1]]` returns `"AAAAAA" "BBBB"`, and not `"AAAAAA"`

Comment: @meedstrom - Because `strsplit('AAAAAA.BBBB', '\\.')` is a list class, adding `[[1]]` will call the first object of the list. The first object of a list can be almost anything, though, like a data frame, a matrix, a plot, or a set of strings--like the what we have here. Thus, to only call `"AAAAAA"` from this list (i.e., the `strsplit`'s first object's first element), we can do `variable = strsplit('AAAAAA.BBBB', '\\.')[[1]][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_split`

```
library(stringr)
str_split(string, fixed("."))[[1]][1]
#[1] "AAAAAA"
```

---

Or using `trimws`

```
trimws(string, whitespace = "\\..*")
#[1] "AAAAAA"
```

#### data

```
string <- 'AAAAAA.BBBB'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string <- 'AAAAAA.BBBB'
result <- strsplit(string, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
#[1] "AAAAAA"
```

You can also do this without splitting with regex removing everything after a period (`.`)

```
sub('\\..*', '', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some simple `regex`:

```
sub('\\..*', '', 'AAAAAA.BBBB')
[1] "AAAAAA"
```